# Кастомный URL в Yii

Tags: php, yii, url

Я хочу в своём приложении создать правила для URL, чтобы некая произвольная ссылка обрабатывалась, как `controller/action/id`. Например, URL `/student` должен обрабатываться, как `user/group/1`, teachers => `user/group/2` и т.д. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

1 вариант. В конфиге у компонента urlManager надо прописать нужные rules
http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.url
Прокрути до блока "Использование именованных параметров", там все написано.

Но этот метод не подходит если тебе надо чтобы правила формировались динамически + если их много, так как может замедлить работу сайта.

2 вариант. Переопределить CUrlManager. Тебя интересуют методы createUrl и parseUrl.